# Nested nodes are not formatted correctly after implementing JsonConverter

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a list of objects that I want to serialize as JSON like below, since there is a complex type in this list. I want to change this complex type to `Key/Value` pairs where each `Key` is the name of a property in the type, and each `Value` is the corresponding value of that property. I've tried multiple solutions but none of them worked for me.

**Here is the object structure**

```
public class Metadata
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    // If I change the type of Metadata to IList<IDictionary<string, object>>
    // custom converter won't catch it at all when I pass it to its constructor
    //public IList<IDictionary<string, object>> Metadata { get; set; }
    public IList<Metadata> Metadata { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

**Here is my desired output with two entries in `IList<Metadata>`**

```
{
    "Metadata": [{
            "Key": "FirstName",
            "Value": "ABC"
        },
        {
            "Key": "LastName",
            "Value": "XYZ"
        },
        {
            "Key": "FirstName",
            "Value": "DEF"
        },
        {
            "Key": "LastName",
            "Value": "MNL"
        }
    ],
    "Length": 25,
    "Type": "application/mp3"
}
```

I know that `JsonSerializer` does not change the face of the object by itself, so I tried to change it by implementing a custom `JsonConverter`:

```
public class KeyValue
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

class CustomMetadataConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly Type[] _types;

    public CustomMetadataConverter(params Type[] types)
    {
        _types = types;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return _types.Any(t => t == objectType);
    }

    // I've removed ReadJson and CanRead here to keep the question clear

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.FromObject(value);

        if (token.Type != JTokenType.Object)
            token.WriteTo(writer);
        else
        {
            JObject jsonObject = (JObject)token;

            IList<KeyValue> properties = jsonObject.Properties()
                .Select(p => new KeyValue { Key = p.Name, Value = p.Value.ToString() }).ToList();

            // If I change the IList<KeyValue> to anonymous array, output would be the same
            //var properties = jsonObject.Properties().Select(p => new { Key = p.Name, Value = p.Value.ToString() }).ToArray();

            jsonObject.RemoveAll();

            jsonObject.Add(new JProperty("Metadata", JToken.FromObject(properties)));
            jsonObject.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how I call it:

```
var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listOfData, Formatting.Indented, new CustomMetadataConverter(typeof(Metadata)));
```

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43902871/12217161) to move it to root, but the output of the custom converter is wrapped with the parent instead of replacing it. I know it's because the custom converter only reads children of `Metadata` but if I change `CustomMetadataConverter(typeof(Metadata))` to `CustomMetadataConverter(typeof(Data))` it converts the whole query to `Key/Value` pairs. And that's not what I want.

**Here is the output after implementing custom converter**

```
{
  "Metadata": [
    {
      "Metadata": [
        {
          "Key": "FirstName",
          "Value": "ABC"
        },
        {
          "Key": "LastName",
          "Value": "XYZ"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Length": 25,
  "Type": "application/mp3"
}
```

Comment: Your converter is doing the right thing.  Your real data model has `IList<Metadata> Metadata`, and each `Metadata` is to be serialized as a list of key/value pairs, so that means the `Metadata` property is going to get serialized as a 2d jagged array not a 1d array as shown in your *desired output*.  Only thing that might be unnecessary is the additional nested `Metadata` object, you could just make it a 2d array without that.

Comment: @abc Right. I think it should be changed from outside of converter. But I've no idea how? If I understand you correctly I should use another type instead of `IList<Metadata>`? But what type is suitable? Moreover I query my database using the exact same model. And something else, If I remove `KeyValue` from conveter and return array instead, the output does not change.

Comment: *But what type is suitable?* -- we;;, what do you want to have appear in the JSON if the `IList<Metadata>` contains two entries?  You only show what should happen with one entry.

Comment: @dbc it's like this: `{"Metadata": [{"Key": "FirstName", "Value": "ABC"}, {"Key": "LastName", "Value": "DEF"}], "Length": 25, "Type": "application/mp3", "Metadata": [{"Key": "FirstName", "Value": "HG"}, {"Key": "LastName", "Value": "XYZ"}], "Length": 26, "Type": "application/mp4"}`

Comment: That's not well-formed JSON.  Upload it to https://jsonlint.com/ and you will get errors.  Could you please edit your question to show what you expect to get with two  `Metadata` entries? -- i.e. a [mcve]?

Comment: @MasLoo With two entries, are you sure you would want to put both into a flat array like that?  The problem then is that it is less clear which key-value objects in the array belong together as part of the same logical Metadata.  In other words, if you were to try to deserialize this JSON at some point in the future, would you be able to reconstruct the original Metadata objects from it?  I think it would be better to use a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: @MasLoo An example of what I mean is shown [here](https://pastebin.com/Vp0EwhzY).

Comment: @BrianRogers  I agree, the example is better than what I need. I tried it by changing `IList<Metadata>` with `Metadata[]` here is it's output: `{"Metadata":[{"Metadata":[{"Key":"FirstName","Value":"Masoud"},{"Key":"LastName","Value":"Shabanloo"}]},{"Metadata":[{"Key":"FirstName","Value":"Farhad"},{"Key":"LastName","Value":"Mehrad"}]}],"Length":25,"Type":"application/json"}`. still wrapped in `Metadata`. `Metadata[][]` would add extra brackets to it. I have no Idea what to do now?

Comment: @MasLoo - so have you decided what JSON you want to generate?  Is it a 2d jagged array as mentioned previously and shown here https://pastebin.com/Vp0EwhzY?  And if you're generating this JSON to upload to some web service, have you checked its documentation?

Comment: @dbc I really appretiate your helps. Brian Rogers helped me out with his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two or more `Metadata` items in the list, and you serialized them to key-value pair objects in a flat array like you described in your question, then it would be difficult to tell which key-value pairs belong together if you need to deserialize the JSON later.  It would be better to use a two-dimensional array structure like this instead:

```
{
  "Metadata": [
    [
      {
        "Key": "FirstName",
        "Value": "ABC"
      },
      {
        "Key": "LastName",
        "Value": "XYZ"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "Key": "FirstName",
        "Value": "DEF"
      },
      {
        "Key": "LastName",
        "Value": "MNL"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "Length": 25,
  "Type": "application/mp3"
}
```

Here is a converter which will do that:

```
class ObjectToKvpArrayConverter<T> : JsonConverter where T : class
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(T);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JArray array = new JArray(
            JObject.FromObject(value)
                   .Properties()
                   .Select(jp => 
                       new JObject(
                           new JProperty("Key", jp.Name),
                           new JProperty("Value", jp.Value)
                       )
                   )
        );
        array.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = new JObject(
            JArray.Load(reader)
                  .Children<JObject>()
                  .Select(jo => new JProperty((string)jo["Key"], jo["Value"]))
        );
        T result = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        serializer.Populate(obj.CreateReader(), result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

You can use the converter like this:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented, new ObjectToKvpArrayConverter<Metadata>());
```

Here is a round-trip demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wx2e9d

Comment: Your kindness is immensely appreciated. It works, but I'm curious why Its output returns as expected only when I remove generic decoration and I remove the generic decoration from ObjectToKvpArrayConverter.

Comment: My bad! I had forgotten to change `CanConvert` method like yours.